# Google Analytics: Filter by custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the enhanced ecommerce tracking from Google Analytics to send data like this in JS to GA:

```
ga("ec:addImpression", {
  brand: null,
  dimension2: "shop123",
  id: 1,
  list: "Search",
  name: "Product 123",
  position: 1
});
ga("send", "pageview");
```

Then, I use the Reporting API to generate some charts. Here, I want to filter by my custom dimension `dimension2`. The request looks like this:

```
{
  "reportRequests":[
    {
      "dateRanges":[
        {
          "startDate":"2016-10-17",
          "endDate":"2016-11-16"
        }
      ],
      "viewId":"132093148",
      "metrics":[
        {
          "expression":"ga:productListViews"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions":[
        {
          "name":"ga:date"
        },
        {
          "name":"ga:dimension2"
        }
      ],
      "dimensionFilterClauses":[
        {
          "filters":[
            {
              "dimension_name":"ga:dimension2",
              "operator":"EXACT",
              "expressions":[
                "shop123"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this returns no results:

```
{
  "reports":[
    {
      "columnHeader":{
        "dimensions":[
          "ga:date",
          "ga:dimension2"
        ],
        "metricHeader":{
          "metricHeaderEntries":[
            {
              "name":"ga:productListViews",
              "type":"INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data":{
        "totals":[
          {
            "values":[
              "0"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**But when I remove the `dimensionFilterClauses`** I get all the results, of course not filtered by `dimension2`.

> Did I anything wrong when filtering for that dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Change your string `dimension_name` for `dimensionName` and try.

As you can see in the examples: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples

```
"dimensionFilter":
              {
                "dimensionName":"ga:browser",
                "operator":"EXACT",
                "expressions":["Safari"]
              }
```